# Usage of "elbowroom"

Tags: meaning, nouns

In German there is the word *Spielraum* which literally translated means "space available for limited movement" and is used for example to describe a limited location/angle tolerance in mechanical bearings or joints and the like, more often however it's used figuratively to describe the range of tolerable actions an individual can take in order to reach certain goals.

The dictionary translates *elbowroom* (among other things) to *Spielraum* and I'd like to know whether it is fine to use it in the same way for describing the range of actions someone is able to take.

Comment: You might also look at *wiggle room*.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, to give someone elbow room figuratively means to give someone space. A similar idiom is "breathing room".

> [**elbow room**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/elbow-room)
>
> space to move around in: *We were tightly squashed in at dinner, with very little elbow room*.
>
> freedom to do what you want: 
>   *At first the management gave the new director plenty of elbow room*.

Comment: Haven't heard of "breathing room" but "elbow room" is correct. The German *Spielraum* literally means "space to play" and that fits the English idiom: "At first the management gave the new director plenty of space to do what he wanted."

Comment: and is it elbow room or elbowroom? i can find both in my online dictionary

Comment: @AndrewLeach: [Breathing room](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/breathing+room) works, too; both are in use in the U.S. Interesting how _breathing room_ seems slower to catch on in the [U.K.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=breathing+room%2Celbow+room&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6) than in the [U.S.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=breathing+room%2Celbow+room&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5).

Comment: @Mat: I guess it can be written [either way](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elbowroom%2Celbow+room&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), though I've usually seen it as two words.

Comment: UK English would use *breathing space*, though illogically often in reference to time.

Comment: I think "breathing space" is more common in the US, too, though "breathing room" is not unheard of.

Comment: I've seen _breathing room_ used in close-fought contests as well, such as elections or sports: "The slim 1-0 margin persisted into the seventh when the Bums gave their pitcher a little breathing room with two more scores." (William F. McNeil, _The Dodgers Encyclopedia_)

Comment: In regards to 'breathing room'. I think he meant 'not enough breathing space'. This is common, and I don't think breathing room exists.

Comment: "Breathing room" is a phrase in the current vernacular, and is often synonymous with "breathing space". It is probably a cross breading between "breathing space" (a more common and older phrase) and "room to breathe".

Answer (score 4):

The literal sense (i.e. - freedom of movement in a joint/bearing) is often called *"**slack**"*, or ["***play***"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22no%20play%20in%20the%20joint%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22play%20in%20the%20bearing%22&oq=%22play%20in%20the%20bearing%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...45767.46456.2.46853.5.5.0.0.0.0.97.330.5.5.0.Zx7HfeP5l1w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902).

***Slack*** (not ***play***) is used figuratively for *people* - but mainly in the idiom [cut someone some slack](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+someone+some+slack), where it usually has the sense of *excusing someone from the consequences of bad choice/action*, rather than giving authority to make choices.

To describe, for example, a junior manager's freedom to take decisions without seeking authority from senior management, we often say he ["*has [considerable] **latitude***"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20has%20considerable%20latitude%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has%20considerable%20latitude%22&oq=%22has%20considerable%20latitude%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...13993.14381.0.14750.3.3.0.0.0.0.110.249.2j1.3.0.OvWy5T0NXBs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902) or ***leeway***.

*Elbow room* (normally two words, or hyphenated) is used figuratively, but my impression is that, for example, ["plenty of elbow room"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22elbow%20room%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22plenty%20of%20elbow%20room%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=IdOaT72MA9Sk8gOLusylBA&sqi=2&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902) usually refers to *physical* space to move freely.

Comment: *spiel* = play IIRC.

Comment: @cornbread ninja: I didn't realise that. So apparently we have pretty much the same idiomatic use of the word for "play" in the first place (a certain amount of freedom of physical movement), but it seems to me (and Kris, I think) that the extension to "making free choices" seems less pronounced in English.

Comment: According to ngrams for some [bearing](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bearing+slop%2Cbearing+slack%2Cbearing+play%2Cbearing+backlash%2Cbearing+leeway%2Cbearing+looseness&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) combinations and [joint](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=joint+slop%2Cjoint+slack%2Cjoint+play%2Cjoint+backlash%2Cjoint+leeway%2Cjoint+looseness&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) combinations, such use of *slack* is negligible, such use depending instead on *play* and *looseness*.  Ngrams with linkage, drive, etc. are similar.

Answer (score -1):

Per your explanation, Spielraum is the 'range of permitted **actions**'. However, elbowroom is more literal --  meaning the **space** for manouvre rather than the actions in the space. By an extended inference, both may imply the same in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: Per the O.P.'s explanation, _spielraum_ refers literally to _space_, and figuratively to _actions_.

Comment: Per explanation, it is otherwise -- pl check again.

Comment: okay, I'll check again... (directly posted from the O.P.) the word Spielraum which **literally translated means "space available for limited movement"** and is used for example to describe a limited location/angle tolerance in mechanical bearings or joints and the like

Comment: Good. Now read my answer.

Comment: I did read your answer, several times: "Spielraum is the 'range of permitted **actions**'. However, elbowroom is more literal..."  The bolding of the word _actions_, your use of the word _however_, and the opening phrase "per your explanation" together imply that the O.P. somehow stated that _spielroom_ is less related to physical space that _elbowroom_, and that _elbowroom_ is more literal than _spielraum_ in that regard – yet this isn't the case.  At least, that's how it comes across to me, even with your conclusion that either one could be used in either sense.

Comment: @J.R.: I'm not quite sure what you mean there, but I think Kris is saying that *elbow-room* is less amenable to figurative extension into *"freedom of **action**"* than *spielraum*. I don't know German, but whilst I agree the English term *can* be used that way, I don't think it's particularly common compared to **spatial** senses such as *"It's a big car, so there's plenty of elbow-room"* - or more figuratively *"It's a big house, so we have plenty of elbow-room"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for the explanation, I think I understand what he was getting at now. Even if you're slightly off, that's some solid speculation on your part. _“Speculation has far more elbow room thanextrapolation; it starts with a_ '_What if?_'” (R.A. Heinlein)

Comment: @J.R.: Not sure what you mean by "slightly off". Have a look in Google Books for *"considerable/plenty of latitude"* and compare them to *"considerable / plenty of elbow room"*. It seems to me both *"considerable"* and *"latitude"* occur more with freedom of ***choice*** rather than ***movement***, whereas with *"elbow room"* it's the other way around.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I meant slightly off in your speculation, since you began with "I think Kris is saying..."  (Really, I was just trying to set up the Heinlein quote, which used "elbow room" and "speculation" in the same sentence, which I thought was apt and cool.)